# Hide printing page x of y dialog box in VB6 using Printer Object. NOT PrintDocument one

Tags: vb.net, vb6, vb6-migration

My code is

```
      Dim p As New Printer
      p.Print("Hello")
      p.EndDoc()
```

I have used

```
Dim k As New System.Drawing.Printing.PreviewPrintController
```

But its giving me compile time error in VB.Net / VB6.

I cannot use PrintDocument and I want to hide that dialog box. Any Help?

Comment: Which are you using, VB6 or VB.Net?

Comment: I am using it in vb.net Project. its migrated from VB6

Comment: And I cant use PrintDocument Object

Comment: @ChrisDunaway Can you please help?

Comment: I don't know of any way to hide the dialog.   What prevents you from using the `PrintDocument` class?

Comment: its a big project, VB6 developer had used Printer object. and its not easy to change that big code using PrintDocument object.

Comment: More code tags and couple of characters changed

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft made a library that helped the transition some from old VB6 code. This may be of some help if you are unable make major changes. Though the version I found with a brief search is pretty dated so can not say how supported it is.

Microsoft Visual Basic Power Packs 3.0 ([Download Link](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25169))

Among the things it contains is the printer control that you old program may be using. ([MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.powerpacks.printing.compatibility.vb6.printer.aspx))

I believe that the libraries where only suppose to be uses in a temporary transitional stage. As a project was intended to be migrated over to using the newer .NET versions of the controls.